# How do I redirect output to stderr in groovy?

Tags: java, scripting, groovy

I'm looking for a way to redirect output in a groovy script to stderr:

```
catch(Exception e) {
    println "Want this to go to stderr"
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just off the top of my head couldn't you do a bit of self-wiring:

```
def printErr = System.err.&println
printErr("AHHH")
```

but that is a bit manual

Comment: It's even possible to redefine println: (`def println = System.err.&println`) - useful at the beginning of a script that writes results to stdout by something like `foo.write(System.in)`

Comment: This throws a `MissingMethodException` if used with a GString. For example this doesn't work: `printErr "Problem with: $aVariable"`

Comment: As this answer is likely grossly outdated, I have made it community editable.

Comment: @MatthiasBraun I can't reproduce your error on 2.4.12: it works with `GString`s.

Answer (score 21):

Groovy has access to the JRE:

```
System.err.println "goes to stderr"
```

Although there may be a more Groovy-fied way...

Comment: Yep, I was hoping for a groovyish way.

Answer (score 19):

Another quite compact alternative is this:

```
System.err << "Want this to go to stderr"
```

Or you could add this at the top of your script

```
def err = System.err
...
err << "Want this to go to stderr"
```

which is what I'm now doing in my groovy shell scripts

Answer (score 1):

If you just want something shorter to type, here are two options.  First, you can import java.lang.System as anything you like, specifically something shorter like "sys":

```
import java.lang.System as sys
sys.err.println("ERROR Will Robinson")
```

Second,  you can assign the System.err stream to a variable and use that variable from then on as an alias for System.err, like:

```
err = System.err
err.println("ERROR again Will Robinson")
```

This has the possible advantage that all the functions of System.err are accessible so you don't have to wire up each one individually (e.g. err.print, err.println, etc.).

Hopefully there is a standard Groovy way, because idiosyncratic renaming can be confusing to people who read your code.