# Convenient print to stderr in spock/groovy

Tags: groovy, spock, stderr

In a spock (groovy) test, I can print to stdout by simply

```
println 'hello world'
```

If I want to print to stderr, I can:

```
System.err.println 'hello world'
```

or even shorter:

```
import static java.lang.System.err

err.println 'hello world'
```

but does groovy have built-in support for a more convenient/terse syntax, eg something like

```
eprintln 'hello world'
```

---

Note: This is not a duplicate of [How do I redirect output to stderr in groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381920/how-do-i-redirect-output-to-stderr-in-groovy), which asks how to print to stderr. This question states how you can print to stderr (in a neater way than the linked question IMHO) but instead asks if there's a **built in** way to print to stderr - ie:

**Is there a method similar to [`DefaultGroovyMethods.print`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#println(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) that prints to stderr?**

Comment: No there isn't. But you can roll your own (see [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381920/how-do-i-redirect-output-to-stderr-in-groovy))

Comment: @tim Then "no" is the answer... thanks. I was hoping for a "groovy" way, like `println` (the "java" way to print to stderr is obvious)

Comment: I quite like the `printErr` solution in the answers